# Cannot connect to Cloud SQL Proxy through GKE with Workload Identity

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql, service-accounts, cloud-sql-proxy

I am following the Google Cloud Platform's guide for connecting to a Cloud SQL instance through a GKE cluster using Cloud SQL Proxy and a Public IP address (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine). However, after trying to deploy my application I get the following error in my container logs.

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 5432 }
```

Followed by the error message

```
2021/02/01 05:35:31 the default Compute Engine service account is not configured with sufficient permissions to access the Cloud SQL API from this VM. Please create a new VM with Cloud SQL access (scope) enabled under "Identity and API access". Alternatively, create a new "service account key" and specify it using the -credential_file parameter
```

In addition (and I assume related) when I check my compute engine for the node in the cluster I see that the Cloud SQL Cloud API access scope is disabled. Is there a way to enable this?

I am aware that there are multiple ways  to connect to a Cloud SQL Instance through a GKE cluster, however, I would like to use workload identity over a credentials file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use the default service account on your Compute Engine VM, you don't need to play with the scope of the VM. The scope are enforced only with the Compute engine default service account, with custom service account, they aren't.

If you use Workload identity on your cluster, it's the same thing (because it's not the Compute Engine default service account which is used but a custom one). And yes prefer this to Service Account key file.

Comment: I am using a kubernetes deployment similar to what is shown in GCP's guide and I have
`serviceAccountName: <YOUR-KSA-NAME>`. My GSA is bound to my KSA and my KSA is annotated properly. Shouldn't this be specifying to use that service account instead of the default?

Comment: Is the Workload Identity installed on your Cluster?

Comment: It was, my issue was a typo in my deployment.yml... I was using `serviceAccount: <YOUR-KSA-NAME>` instead of `serviceAccountName: <YOUR-KSA-NAME>`.

Comment: @JestGames Weird, I made the same exact mistake. Can't find an error in the documentation though

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the similar exception while following the guide [Connect to Cloud SQL for MySQL from Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-instance-kubernetes#node.js)

Finally, it has turned out, that Workload Identity was not enabled fully on my Kubernetes cluster. So, in case of using Workload Identity approach, you should ensure:

1. Workload Identity is enabled in your [cluster settings](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#enable-existing-cluster). This was turned on in my case.
2. Your [node pool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#option_2_node_pool_modification) is also updated to use Workload Identity. If not, execute the following:

> 

```
gcloud container node-pools update NODEPOOL_NAME \
    --cluster=CLUSTER_NAME \
    --zone=YOUR_CLUSTER_ZONE or --region=YOUR_CLUSTER_REGION \
    --workload-metadata=GKE_METADATA
```

After these steps my gke-sql deployment became green.